# How do I access multiple HTML select elements in a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, html, select, for-loop

Here is the gist of my HTML..

```
<form name="formName">
<select name="mySelect" onchange="">
            <option value="value 1">option 1</option>
            <option value="value 2">option 2</option>
            <option value="value 3">option 3</option>
            <option value="value 4">option 4</option>
            <option value="value 5">option 5</option>
            <option value="value 6">option 6</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

This code is written 32 times in 32 different `<td>`s in a table.  My goal is to access each `<select>` element with a for loop and assign whatever value is selected to a variable.  I have not been able to do this so far.  I would like to see how this is done without using jquery but if jquery is the best way I am open to ideas.

Comment: Show us what you have tried either with or without jquery.

Comment: To want variable you want to assign the values?

Comment: So you want to define 32 variables? This doesn't make sense. What do you want to do with those variables? One uses an array in this case.

Comment: put them all in the same `<form>` group

Comment: What are your criteria for "best"? Putting them all in a form and then accessing them as members of the form's *elements* collection is fast, compliant with all browsers since forever and doesn't require any library or special features.

Comment: I have tried a number of different ways.  One way was this one where I assumed the <select> element would work as an array.
    for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
 x = document.timeTable.select[i].value;
    }
Another way was to name each <select> "select1", "select2", and so on and then do the for loop..
    for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
 xi = document.timeTable.selecti.value;
    }

What I am trying to do is have each <option> have a numeric value and identical <options> be summed into a variable, leaving me with only 6 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they all have the `.mySelect` class. If not, just add a common class to all of them.

**JS Solution**

```
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName("mySelect");
for (i = 0; i < selects .length; i++) { 
    console.log(selects[i]);
}
```

**JQuery Solution**

```
$('.mySelect').each(
    function(index, value) {
        console.log(value);
});
```

[JQuery Each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Thanks a ton!  The JS solution is what I was looking for and it worked great!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of selecting the `select` elements and storing the values in an  array using vanilla JavaScript:

```
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('table select');
var values = Array.prototype.map.call(selects, function(sel) {
   return sel.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can all the values to an array, that's a better way of doing it. Try the following

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var selects = [];
    $('select').each(function(i){
        selects.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(selects);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="mySelect" onchange="">
  <option value="value 1">option 1</option>
  <option value="value 2">option 2</option>
  <option value="value 3">option 3</option>
  <option value="value 4">option 4</option>
  <option value="value 5">option 5</option>
  <option value="value 6">option 6</option>
</select>

<select name="mySelect" onchange="">
  <option value="value 1">option 1</option>
  <option value="value 2">option 2</option>
  <option value="value 3">option 3</option>
  <option value="value 4">option 4</option>
  <option value="value 5">option 5</option>
  <option value="value 6">option 6</option>
</select>

<button>Run!</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

AngularJS solution:

```
// table.html
<table ng-controller="tableController">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in tableRows">
    <td ng-repeat="col in row.cols">
      <ng-include ng-src="tableElement.html">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

// tableElement.html
<form>
  <select ng-change="selectChanged($event, row, col)">
    <option value="value 1">option 1</option>
    <option value="value 2">option 2</option>
    <option value="value 3">option 3</option>
    <option value="value 4">option 4</option>
    <option value="value 5">option 5</option>
    <option value="value 6">option 6</option>
  </select>
</form>

// tableController.js
$scope.selectChanged = function($event, row, col){
  // update the table, send an http request, or whatever
  // not sure of the syntax here to get the changed selection:
  $values[row][col] = $event.target.value;
}
//////////////////////
```

Comment: OP asks for no jq and u jump in with another js framework, just look below at the simple 2 line solution in pure js.

Comment: true, the value of this alternative is that it will update the javascript variable values when the selects change. with the 2 line solution, the javascript variables will only be set once, when the function is run. it sounds like that suffices, grats OP